# MSBuild warnings caused by Google.Apis.Storage.v1 build 1.45.0.1957

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I implemented a project to store some files in the GCP storage bucket by using Google.Apis.Storage.v1 build 1.45.0.1957 and I am having msbuild warnings for the projects which does not have any direct reference to the project where I use the library.

warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:

details from our build

There was a conflict between "Google.Apis.Storage.v1, Version=1.45.0.1957, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" and "Google.Apis.Storage.v1, Version=1.45.0.1882, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab".
No way to resolve conflict between "Google.Apis.Storage.v1, Version=1.45.0.1957, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" and "Google.Apis.Storage.v1, Version=1.45.0.1882, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab". Choosing "Google.Apis.Storage.v1, Version=1.45.0.1957, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" arbitrarily.
References which depend on "Google.Apis.Storage.v1, Version=1.45.0.1957, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" [C:\Jenkins\workspace\code\tools\api\Project.Test.Proxy\bin\Debug\Google.Apis.Storage.v1.dll].
C:\Jenkins\workspace\code\tools\api\Project.Test.Proxy\bin\Debug\ExternalStorage.GCP.dll
Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Jenkins\workspace\code\tools\api\Project.Test.Proxy\bin\Debug\ExternalStorage.GCP.dll".
C:\Jenkins\workspace\code\tools\api\Project.Test.Proxy\bin\Debug\Project.Test.Proxy.dll
References which depend on "Google.Apis.Storage.v1, Version=1.45.0.1882, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" [].
C:\Jenkins\workspace\code\tools\api\Project.Test.Proxy\bin\Debug\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.dll
Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Jenkins\workspace\code\tools\api\Project.Test.Proxy\bin\Debug\Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.dll".
C:\Jenkins\workspace\code\tools\api\Project.Test.Proxy\bin\Debug\Project.Test.Proxy.dll
There was a conflict between "Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.45.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" and "Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.44.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab".
No way to resolve conflict between "Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.45.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" and "Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.44.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab". Choosing "Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.45.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" arbitrarily.

How come it complains about 1.45.0.1882 if I install and use 1.45.0.1957.

What might be the source of this reference mess ?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

The deep scan found the broken reference in one .csproj file of our solution.